# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.influxdb'

Tags: python, pip, module, airflow, influxdb

I'm trying to run some InfluxDB queries with Apache Airflow but I keep getting the same error message. I did everything following this docs (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-influxdb/stable/index.html) And I downloaded the correct packages making sure I download the correct version as well.
I tried reinstalling apache-airflow-providers-influxdb package and downgrading the version but I still get the same error.
I hope someone encountered this before and can help me.

I'm working on Windows, I tried it on Ubuntu WSL but still got the same error. I'm using python 3.11.2.
This is my code

```html
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.providers.influxdb.hooks.influxdb import InfluxDBHook
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import socket
import telnetlib

from influxdb_client import Point


urls = 
token =
organization = 


@task(task_id="fetch_system_stats")
def fetch_system_stats():

    influxdb_hook = InfluxDBHook()
    client = influxdb_hook.get_conn()

    # Fetch system stats from InfluxDB
    tables = client.query('''
        from(bucket: "a1hrinfra/autogen")
        |> range(start: -5m)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "system")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "uptime")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["osmajor"] == )
        |> filter(fn: (r) => not (r["host"] =~ /^xlvp.*|^xlvt.*|^lx.*/))
        |> group(columns: ["host"])
        |> last(column: "_time")
    ''')

    # Get IP addresses of hosts
    ips = []
    for row in tables:
        ips.append(row['host'])

    # Connect to each host with telnet to check availability
    for ip in ips:
        try:
            tn = telnetlib.Telnet(ip, 22, timeout=5)
            tn.close()
            data = Point("system").tag("live host", ip).field("response", "Available")
            influxdb_hook.write(bucket="bucket", org=organization, record=data)
        except Exception as e:
            data = Point("system").tag("live host", ip).field("response", f"Not available: {e}")
            influxdb_hook.write(bucket="bucket", org=organization, record=data)

def get_host(ip):
    return socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]

with DAG(
    dag_id="influx_server_availabilty",
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:
    fetch_system_stats()
```

Comment: Please show us your code. What is your python version?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to put the code in.